# Computing the values of a std::map of vector as the key and double as the value?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, stdmap

```
 std::map<std::vector<double>, double> MyMethod(std::map<std::vector<double>, double> mappingSourceToTarget, int radius)
{
    std::map<std::vector<double>, double> mappingSourceToTargetNew(mappingSourceToTarget);
    std::map<std::vector<double>, double>::iterator it_trgt,it_src;
    double sumOfNormals1 = 0;
    int size = mappingSourceToTarget.size(), i=0;
    for (it_src = mappingSourceToTarget.begin(), it_trgt = mappingSourceToTargetNew.begin(); i < size + (radius * 2) ; i++, it_src, it_trgt++)
    {
        auto elem = mappingSourceToTargetNew;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            //it_trgt->first.at(i % size) = it_src->first.at(i%size);

            mappingSourceToTargetNew.at(i % size) = mappingSourceToTarget.at(i % size);
            sumOfNormals1 += mappingSourceToTarget.at(i % size);
```

Here I am having trouble , regarding how should put the values from one map to another.

I am using the concept of circular arrays so i%size is being used here, 
the vector is the coordinates and the double is the intensity values at that point.

The index thing is not working with .at(), I really don't know what to do as

I have to make it work by using maps only (task).

copying the values from one map to another at the index (i%size)

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I think you a heading in a wrong direction with the posted code. Some parts of it makes little sense. I think this is an XY problem (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So if you can explain **what** you want the function to do, someone may be able to help.

Comment: The key type in the maps is `std::vector<double>`, so the `at()` member function expects *that* as a parameter, not an `int`. On top of that, having floating point values as keys makes the code extremely delicate, as a difference in - say - the 15th decimal will produce a different key.

Comment: A MovingAverage function is what I want, if there is any other way to do that kindly please reply .. The data that is inside the   Value of this map is what i want to put through a moving average algorithm and store it in my map .

Answer (score 0):

1) Read the key-value using an iterator, i.e. using first/second.

2) When the iterator reach the end, set it equal to begin(). That will function like `i % size`

Here is some sample code to show the idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m {{1, 100}, {2, 200}};
    auto s = m.size();
    std::cout << "size = " << s << std::endl;
    auto i1 = m.begin();
    auto i2 = m.end();
    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "key=" << i1->first << " value=" << i1->second << std::endl;
        ++i1;
        if (i1 == i2)
        {
            // We reached the end so go back to the begining
            i1 = m.begin();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
size = 2
key=1 value=100
key=2 value=200
key=1 value=100
key=2 value=200
key=1 value=100
```

Comment: But here I have to copy from one map to another.

Comment: The loop is going till i < size +(radius * 2)

Comment: @NamanSharma The code here is just to show you how you get access to the key-values in a cyclic manner. As you noticed yourself it can't be done with `.at(i%size)` but you can do it like the posted code. What you want to do with the key-value pair is up to you. Copying into another map is no problem.

Comment: BTW: I don't understand what you want to achieve by copying into a map in a circular way. A specific key can only be in the map one time.

Comment: And further: In your code you already make a copy in this line: `std::map<std::vector<double>, double> mappingSourceToTargetNew(mappingSourceToTarget);`

Comment: This code was written by someone else passed to me, and I was told to make it compile somehow by using only map. I totally understand that there is no point of using map here as here operations are being done only at the value part of the map, So if we need index there is no point of using a key value pair. Iam using a std::vector instead now